# Table of (integral) cohomology groups of K(Z,n)

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology

Can I find somewhere a table of the (first few) cohomology groups of $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ with integer coefficients?

It seems like a natural counterpart to the table of the homotopy groups of spheres, but I couldn’t find anything. I’m aware of exposé 11, année 7 in the Cartan seminar where the homology of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is computed, and I guess I could adapt it to the case where the group is $\mathbb{Z}$ and use the universal coefficient theorem to get the cohomology, but it’s not completely trivial, and I would be surprised that nobody thought about doing it before me.

Comment: I would guess that books about cohomology operations would be a good place to look

Comment: The answer to the stable question (i.e. the integral cohomology of $H\mathbb{Z}$) is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50519/integral-cohomology-stable-operations. Maybe there's something of interest for you there.

Comment: I'll add that the lack of interest compared to the case of $F_p$ is perhaps due to the fact that $H\mathbb{Z}$ is not a flat cohomology theory, and so it has no nice Adams spectral sequence that could serve as an application of the structure of the integral Steenrod algebra.

Comment: There is a paper "Integral cohomology operations" by Stan Kochman that treats the stable case, and this agrees with the unstable case through a range.  However, the answer is unpleasant.  I think that all possible applications can be done more cleanly using a combination of $H\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $H\mathbb{Q}$, or sometimes by using $K$-theory or complex cobordism instead.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no complete source besides the Cartan seminar. Of course, the homology computation gives the cohomology computation immediately. However, if you are only interested in the first **few** groups, then you might be able to get away with just iteratively using the Serre spectral sequences for the fibrations $$K(\mathbb{Z},n-1)\rightarrow\star\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z},n).$$ Since you know the integral cohomology of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ with its ring structure, and since the spectral sequences play well with the ring structure, it is not a difficult exercise to compute $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z},n),\mathbb{Z})$ for $*\leq 3n$ or so for any given $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 6):

There are several computations carried out explicitly in the paper

*Samuel Eilenberg and Saunders Mac Lane*, MR 65162 [**On the groups $H(\Pi,n)$. II. Methods of computation**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=65162), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **60** (1954), 49--139.

For instance, I once wanted to know the groups $H_{4+i}(K(\mathbb{Z},4);\mathbb{Z})$ for $i\le 3$, and was able to extract the answer from Section 24.

Comment: Was this by chance for a MU or MO-bordism computation?

Comment: @BenjaminAntieau: Ha ha, almost! We were working out the first few stages of the Postnikov tower of $MO(2)$, in order to study realization of codimension 2 cohomology classes by embeddings.

Comment: @MarkGrant that is so flippin' cool. I will have to look up that paper. I guess it is obvious which it is from the title?

Comment: @SeanTilson: Thanks! And yes, I think there's only one paper with that title!